# What should I take into consideration when creating AD users in PowerShell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

The current way AD users are created is:

1. The employee determines which department the new hire is assigned
2. A current user from that same OU is copied to create the new user

The problem with this method is that some of the attributes that we'd like to start using (and others that we already use) are not always being updated.

To fix this, I wrote out a script to prompt users for various information (new hire's name, position, title, department they're going in, etc). The account is then created in the appropriate OU with appropriate memberships, etc.

My question is, what should I know (that may or may not be blatantly obvious) about creating AD Users via PowerShell? Are there any pros and cons?

Thanks!